# Is there a way to create a (Excel workbook) File using Microsoft Graph API, but not by uploading

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to do something like

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/workbook/add

or similar which will create a new workbook identical to what the New -> Workbook menu does in the OneDrive Web interface.

I can't create the file locally so upload is not an option.

Comment: Can someone check and provide answer, based on the new API v1.0 ?
If incase it supports in the newer version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph APIs only allow reading and modifying workbooks that already exist at this time.

I realize that your question stated you were not able to create the file locally. However, a library like [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) has the ability to create workbooks in-memory that you could then push up into OneDrive using the Graph APIs. You could use a library like that to create a blank workbook, push it, then manipulate it using the Graph APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert. That's helpful. After reading the license information though I'm not going to use js-xlsx. But the idea is a good one.

Comment: Are there any links, where it is mentioned that we cannot create a workbook using ms-graph APIs?