# How does one create an empty Excel workbook via API?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm trying to create an empty Excel workbook in OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API. I've tried a variety of requests but OneDrive does not pick up that it is Excel just based on the extension. The only examples I've found are C# SDK examples and I'm looking to do this in another language without an SDK

The following creates the file but creates it with a mime-type of `application/octet-stream`

```
PUT /v1.0/me/drive/items/root:/NewWorkbook.xlxs:/content HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>

{
  "name": "NewWorkbook.xlxs",
  "file": {

  }
}
```

I found a similar ask from a few years ago but Microsoft Graph has undergone a lot of changes since then so I would assume the answers to be somewhat dated https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901596/10255083

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no Microsoft Graph API to create an empty Excel workbook in OneDrive. Besides using the API of Upload a DriveItem as you mentioned, another option is to use the API of Copy a DriveItem, which, however, requires to have an Excel workbook file in OneDrive before the operation.

Answer (score 0):

There is an office JS API called [createWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.workbookcreated?view=excel-js-preview) API, it can create an workbook, but it seems this API not yet expose to Excel Graph, therefore graph doesn't support create an empty workbook.

if you have an excel add-in you can use this API to create a workbook, or if you don't want to open the workbook, then maybe you could use a workaround to duplicate a pre-saved empty workbook and then use Graph API to update the duplicated workbook.